# Show Hide Component via child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I Have two step components in parent component whose state is:

```
state = {
        isStep1Active: true,
        isStep2Active: false,
}
```

This is the initial state set in Parent's constructor:

```
this.state = {
        isStep1Active: true,
        isStep2Active: false,
}
```

In constructor itself I have binded this state via functions so that I can change the state in child component:

```
 this.showStep2Func = this.showStep2Func.bind(this);
 this.hideStep1Func = this.hideStep1Func.bind(this);
```

This method will be sent to the child component which's declared in parent component:

```
showStep2Func() {
    this.setState({
        isStep2Active: true
    });
}
hideStep1Func() {
    this.setState({
        isStep1Active: false
    });
}
```

This's my div of both the components present in parent component:

```
<div className="tab-content">
                            {
                                this.state.isStep1Active ?
                                    <div className="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                                        <Merchant1CreateAccountForm hideStep1={this.hideStep1Func} showStep2={this.showStep2Func} />
                                    </div>
                                    : null
                            }
                            {
                                this.state.isStep2Active ?
                                    <div className="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
                                        <Merchant2EmailVerificationForm/>
                                    </div>
                                    : null
                            }
</div>
```

On the basis of response which carries stepNumber, I wish to hide and show the components in first child component.(My child component uses hook, although that's just syntax) I wish to do something like this:

```
if (stepNumber==="2"){
       props.showStep2();
       props.hideStep1();
       }
```

How shall I re-render my parent component? The above code doesn't re-render the parent component hiding and showing respective components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, this worked after npm start.
Not sure why it wasn't working before.